# Ant: exclude files/directories while svn checkout using ant

Tags: svn, ant

I am struck with the issue, in which i want to checkout a particular directory/files.

**svn://myrepo/sample/tag/version

|

|---SQL

|---ORACLE

|---MYSQL**

For Example, from my svn structure, in this I want to checkout only SQL and MYSQL.

Just like ((((( **fileset excludes="*"**  )))) which helped me a lot.

Comment: Just checkout the desired directories. For example "svn://myrepo/sample/tag/version/SQL"

Comment: Mark - I have a directory where with sub-directories which has both wanted and unwanted directories. I want to check out only those directories instead of checkout the whole just like what<fileset exclude="**/*my_dir*/*"> task does for local directories

Comment: Your options are limited. The cvs task doesn't support filesets: https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/cvs.html

Comment: Thanks Mark. I made a workaround of checking out all the directories and moving the required directories and deleting the others. Though this looks like a big workaround, but i have no other option than checking out the required folders only. And It works fine for me :) :)

Comment: You may want to do some thinking on re-working your repository layout so you don't have to fight this fight.

Comment: If you have access to the SVN executable, you can run a shallow SVN Checkout followed by selective SVN Updates: `svn co --depth [empty|files|immediates] URL` and then `svn up --set-depth infinity ORACLE SQL`.